# How to change Javascript values without page load

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, dom-events

I am working on time counter. There is bidding happening for a product which is supposed to end at 4PM. But at 3PM organizer decides to change the time to 5PM. Now new time (of bidding end) we are sending to client browser using websocket. But Javascript based time counter works on page load only. How can I pass the new Target time without page load in client side browser?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
TargetDate = "12/31/2014 5:00 AM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src= " ./countdown.js "></script>
```

Comment: Create a function that will accept a change in `TargetDate` and call that function when the organizer makes the change.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax..

Comment: @latheesan-kanes Ajax will not work because i need time counter update on real time basis. Ajax will work with certain time interval. And this will put additional load on server.

Comment: @Jay We can call the function on certain event e.g. page load or click, but the project requirement is, it should update as and when new time is received without any event.

Comment: How is the new time received? There has to be some sort of event.

Comment: @JayBlanchard using websockets

Comment: How are you subscribing to the data traversing the socket? BTW - this should have all been included in your original post instead of having us try to harvest the information.